# Pentaho: add another column based on another column

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I have this situation, I have data about age, and I want to add another **column**, with **age range**:

- Range 1 (0-18 years) = children;
- Range 2 (19-50) = adults;
- Range 3 (50+) older people

How can I do this in Pentaho? I have already tried it with filters and so on, but I didn't success. So I want to have an output shown on picture below (for about 100k rows, so i can't do it manually).

Target data [AgeRang column added]:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step you are looking for is named `Number range`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a step called `User Defined Java Expression` which filters data using `Java expression` and adds new column `age_range` to record stream's row.

Use this statement in `Java expression` field:

- `(age <= 18) ? 1 : (age <= 50) ? 2 : 3`

Check following figure from execution:
[image]